# How can I check if 2 ranges intersect in any way in ruby?

Tags: ruby, range

I am attempting to code hitboxes within Gosu in ruby, and want to check if 2 ranges meet (the ranges being co-ords) i want it to simply give true or false

I've looked into it and found the range.cover? code, however after testing this shows it only checks if one range entirely fits inside another, and not if they only partially connect.

```rb
#both sprites are arrays, with the following structure
#[image_data, sprite_x, sprite_y]
#image_data.width would return how wide the image is
#The x and y is the top left of the sprite
  def hit_scan(sprite1, sprite2)
    x_connect = (sprite1[1]..sprite1[1] + sprite1[0].width).cover?(sprite2[1]..(sprite2[1] + sprite2[0].width))
    y_connect = (sprite1[2]..sprite1[2] + sprite1[0].height).cover?(sprite2[2]..(sprite2[2] + sprite2[0].height)
    if x_connect == true
      if y_connect == true
        return true
      else
        return false
      end
    else
      return false
    end
  end
```

This is what I tried, and only returns true when the entire sprite is in the other one.

I expected that whenever the sprites touched, it would return a true statement, but only when one sprite is in another does it return true.

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? You don't want to see others?

Comment: I've received an answer that answers my question and works, it doesn't stop others from answering with their own,

Comment: What you say is true, but once a selection has been made some members may have less incentive to post an answer, choosing instead to move on to another question. For the same reason, flaws in selected answers are less likely to be caught if they are they are the subject of fewer eyeballs. Consider also that some readers may be working on answers when the selection is made. That can happen anytime, of course, but one generally does not expect the selection to be made so quickly. Lastly, there is no rush to make a selection; many here wait at least a couple of hours.

Comment: Note that you can replace the nested `if`s and `return`s with `x_connect && y_connect`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if one range includes begin or end of another one:

```
r1 = (1..5)
r2 = (4..8)

r1.include?(r2.begin) || r1.include?(r2.end) || r2.include?(r1.begin) || r2.include?(r1.end)
```

In your case:

```
r1 = (sprite1[1]..sprite1[1] + sprite1[0].width)
r2 = (sprite2[1]..sprite2[1] + sprite2[0].width)
r1.include?(sprite2[1]) || r1.include?(sprite2[1] + sprite2[0].width) || 
  r2.include(sprite1[1]) || r2.include(sprite1[1] + sprite1[0].width)
```

assuming that the ranges are not endless.

Comment: I tried it after removing the extra ) you've accidentally put in, and it errors out saying `undefined method '+@' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: fixed it, try now

Comment: Careful: `(1...10).end == (1..10).end` and `(1..).end == nil` so there are edge cases in general.

Comment: What if `r2 = 0..8`?

Comment: Fixed for `0..8`

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of cases to consider, as pointed out by @muistooshort in a comment.

I assume that the elements of the ranges are integers, as in the example.

**Code**

The easiest way to determine if two ranges intersect is to negate an expression that determines if they don't intersect.

```
def overlap?(r1, r2)
  return false if r1.size.zero? || r2.size.zero?
  !(range_last(r1) < r2.begin || range_last(r2) < r1.begin) 
end

def range_last(r)
  return Float::INFINITY if r.end==Float::INFINITY || r.end.nil?
  r.include?(r.end) ? r.end : r.end-1  
end
```

**Examples**

```
overlap? 1..3, 2..5                               #=> true 
overlap? 1..3, 4..5                               #=> false 
overlap? 3..1, 0..5                               #=> false 
overlap? 1..4, 4..8                               #=> true 
overlap? 1...4, 4..8                              #=> false 
overlap? 4.., 1..4                                #=> true 
overlap? 4.., 1...4                               #=> false 
overlap? -Float::INFINITY..Float::INFINITY, 1..1  #=> true
overlap? -Float::INFINITY..7, 7..8                #=> true
overlap? -Float::INFINITY...7, 7..8               #=> false 
overlap? -4..Float::INFINITY, -6..-4              #=> true 
overlap? -4..Float::INFINITY, 6...-4              #=> false
```

Observe that the range `3..1` in the 3<sup>rd</sup> example is empty.

Note also:

```
range_last(1..)                                   #=> Infinity 
range_last(1..Float::INFINITY)                    #=> Infinity 
range_last(1..3)                                  #=> 3 
range_last(1...3)                                 #=> 2
```

If the two ranges, `r1` and `r2`, are finite and of the two-dot variety one can replace `range_last(r)` with `r.last`.

Comment: I'm not so sure about `r.include?(r.end) ? r.end : r.end-1`, though... You assume it's an integer range, right?

Comment: @Eric, yes. See my second sentence. You’ve been [AWOL](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/AWOL).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have [endless Ranges](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Range.html#class-Range-label-Endless+Ranges), maybe you could consider to use the Set intersection method [Set#&](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.4/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-26):

```
require 'set'

def overlap?(a, b)
  (a.to_set & b.to_set).any?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `.overlaps?` if you're using Rails.

Rails has had a method on `Range` called `overlaps?` since Rails 3:

```rb
r1 = (1..5)
r2 = (4..8)
r1.overlaps?( r2 ) #=> true

r3 = (6..10)
r1.overlaps?( r3 ) #=> false
r2.overlaps?( r3 ) #=> true
```

Super handy if you're using Rails or want to look at the implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Aren't you guys making it too difficult ?
Maybe I miss something but the easy way to check for intersections is as follows.

```
#use the splat operator `*` to change our range to an array
r1 = *(1..5) # [1 , 2 , 3 , 4, 5]
r2 = *(4..8) # [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
# and give the intersection with the intersection operator &
# if it is an empty array, they don't intersect
r1 & r2 # [4, 5]
# or 
(r1 & r2).any? # true
```

Note: the order of the arrays doesn't matter for the result.

Comment: Sure, but you only consider ranges with a finite number of integers, and you potentially create huge, mostly useless arrays.